# Running a list of custom funcs in parallel, outside of main

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have the following line being called from within a particular area of my script:

```
data = [extract_func(domain, response) for domain, response, extract_func in responses]
```

Basically I collected a bunch of webpage responses asynchronously using aiohttp in the variable `responses` which is nice and fast and so we've already got that. Problem is that the parsing of those responses (using Beautiful Soup) is not asynchronous so I have to parallelize that some other way.

(Each extract_func is technically one of many different various extraction functions that were pre-packaged with the response data so that I call the right Beautiful Soup parsing code for each page. The domain is passed in too for other packaging purposes.)

Anyways I don't know how I'd run all these extraction functions at the same time and then collect the results. I tried looking into multiprocessing but it doesn't seem to apply here / requires that you launch it directly from main, whereas this collection process of mine is taking place from within another function.

I tried this for example (where each extract_function, at the end, adds the returned result to some global list - then here I try):

```
global extract_shared
extract_shared = []
proc = []

for domain, response, extract_func in responses:
    p = Process(target=extract_func, args=(domain, response))
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)

for p in proc:
    p.join()

data = extract_shared
```

However this still seems to move along super slowly, and I end up with no data anyway so my code is still wrong.

Is there a better way I should be going about this?

Is this correct?

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
result_objects = [pool.apply_async(extract_func, args=(domain, response)) for domain, response, extract_func in responses]
data = [r.get() for r in result_objects]
pool.close()
pool.join()
return data
```

Comment: So python doesn't allow multitasking normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `extract_shared` list as you have defined it exists as individual instances in each process's address space. You need to have a shared memory implementation of `extract_shared` so that each process is appending to the same list. If I knew what type of data was being appended, I might be able to recommend which flavor of [`multiprocessing.Array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=array#multiprocessing.Array) to use. Alternatively, although it carries a bit more overhead to use, a [*managed* `list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=syncmanager#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) that is created by a [`multiprocessing.SyncManager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=syncmanager#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) and functions just like a regular list, might be simpler to use.

Using a multiprocessing pool is the way to go. If your worker functions are not returning meaningful results, there is no need to save the the `AsyncResult` instances returned by the call to `ApplyAsync`. Simply calling `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` is sufficient to wait for all outstanding submitted tasks to complete.

```py
import multiprocessing


def init_pool(the_list):
    global extract_shared
    extract_shared = the_list


# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # compute pool size required but no greater than number of CPU cores we have:
    n_processes = min(len(responses), multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    # create a managed list:
    extract_shared = multiprocessing.Manager().list()
    # Initialize each process in the pool's global variable extract_shared with our extract_shared
    # (a managed list can also be passed as another argument to the worker function instead)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(n_processes, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(extract_shared,))
    for domain, response, extract_func in responses:
        pool.apply_async(extract_func, args=(domain, response))
    # wait for tasks to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # results in extract_shared
    print(extract_shared)
```

**Update**

If is easier just to have the worker functions return the results and the main process do the appending. And you had essentially the correct code for that except I would limit the pool size to less than the number of CPU cores you have if the number of tasks you are submitting is less than that number.

Comment: `You need to have a shared memory implementation of extract_shared so that each process is appending to the same list.` I wasn't super clear in my post but what I mean is that I had a list called `extract_shared` outside of all the functions, and then inside each `extract_func` I would do `global extract_shared` and then append the results to `extract_shared` from each function. Does that address that part?

Comment: Each piece of data being appended is an array of tuples, and the tuples contain various strings etc.

Comment: Also what is wrong/different about what I had tried, `result_objects = [pool.apply_async(extract_func, args=(domain, response)) for domain, response, extract_func in responses]` and then `data = [r.get() for r in result_objects]` ?

Comment: And what about calling all of this from outside of main? Can I work around that by just putting `mp.freeze_support()` under `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Comment: To your first comment: NO! I saw what you had coded and it was on the basis of that I had written my answer since what you were doing was not adequate. You can define `extract_shared` outside of all functions (at global scope) but under Windows each process when created starts executing from the top of the program and re-executes this statement and re-creates this list in its own address space and thus is working with its own copy. Even under Linus, where execution does not start from the top, each process gets a copy of the main process's address space.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `result_objects = [pool.apply_async(extract_func, args=(doma ... etc`. And I said so in my answer as long as your worker functions are *returning* results with `return` statements. My answer is addressing the case where instead of returning the results back to the main process for appending, the worker functions themselves were appending the results to `extract_shared` and why your current code would not work in that case.

Comment: The code I am trying in your answer doesn't seem to be grabbing the results from the extract_funcs for some reason (I know this is probably because you are working with imperfect information here), all I can say is that each function is returning a list of tuples, but nothing's showing up in `extract_shared` after the pool close/join

Comment: `mp.freeze_support()` is only relevant if you are creating an EXE file. If you put your process-creating code in a function that is called from the outside, I would think you would be OK.

Comment: If you are doing `data = [r.get() for r in result_objects]` you should at that point have all your results in `data`, **not `extract_shared`** (and in fact there is no real need to even do `pool.close(); pool.join()` afterwards).

Comment: The code I have in my post (first snippet) was the attempt with extract_shared, the second attempt is just its own thing where it collects directly-returned results rather than a global-append, but yes in the second one I go from data directly. It works, just wondering if I am doing it right because it's still not as fast as I would hope but maybe that's normal. Talking it out / seeing your examples has been helpful though so I'll accept as answer. Thanks!

Comment: There is overhead in (1) Creating the pool and (2) Passing arguments from one address space to another (via a queue). If the worker functions are relatively trivial CPU-wise, you might find that multiprocessing actually will hurt performance.

Comment: I said earlier, **If you put your process-creating code in a function that is called from the outside, I would think you would be OK.** I did not mean to imply that you still do not need `if __name__ == '__main__':` controlling the code that launces the entire program (this code ultimately runs process-creating code). I believe that *all* the loaded Python files (i.e. the initial and imported files) will be executed from the top under platforms that use `spawn` to create processes, such as Windows.